# How to round this in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

we just started our studying on SQL and I seem to have a slight problem with one exercise.

I would need to round the result of

```
SELECT AVG(points) AS Average FROM table;
```

I was trying to do it with subquery but I just did not hit the correct one even tough similar subqueries with only select seem to work well.

Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by round? you mean `ROUND()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175003.aspx)

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(POINTS), 2) AS Average
FROM table;
```

Comment: Seems like I did not just write it correctly when I used something like that ^^ Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT ROUND(AVG(POINTS), 3) AS Average FROM your_table;

                             ^^--if you want round by two decimals then use 2 and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ROUND()` function.

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(POINTS), 1) AS Average FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Round(Avg(Points),2) as Average from table

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx
Does this help ?